# What is the original source of the common Ziegler-Nichols PID tuning coefficients?

Tags: control-theory, pid-control

In many places, including but not limited to [the Wikipedia page about PID controllers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#Ziegler%E2%80%93Nichols_method), I see the following PID coefficients: $K_P = 0.6K_U$, $K_I = 1.2 K_U / T_U$, and $K_D = 0.075 K_UT_U$. When were these constants first introduced? The sources point to the papers  *[Optimum Settings for Automatic Controllers](http://davidr.no/iiav3017/papers/Ziegler_Nichols_%201942.pdf)* and *Rule-Based Autotuning Based on Frequency Domain Identification*, but I cannot find these values there.

Table I in the second mentioned paper introduces $K_C = 0.6K_U$, $T_i = 0.5T_U$, and $T_D = 0.125T_U$, but I do not understand what those coefficients mean and how I go to $K_P$, $K_I$, and $K_D$ from there.

Comment: https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Industrial_and_Systems_Engineering/Book%3A_Chemical_Process_Dynamics_and_Controls_(Woolf)/09%3A_Proportional-Integral-Derivative_(PID)_Control/9.03%3A_PID_Tuning_via_Classical_Methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PID, Ziegler, Nichols ([Optimum Settings for Automatic Controllers](http://davidr.no/iiav3017/papers/Ziegler_Nichols_%201942.pdf)) cites:

$K_p = 0.6K_u$, $T_i = 0.5 T_u$, and $T_d = 0.125 T_u$.

[image]

Which McCormack ([Rule-based autotuning based on frequency domain identification](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3331995_Rule-based_autotuning_based_on_frequency_domain_identification)) and [Ziegler-Nichols Tuning Rules for PID](https://www.mstarlabs.com/control/znrule.html) agree with.

[image]

[image]

OP cites [Wikipedia PID coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziegler%E2%80%93Nichols_method): $K_p = 0.6K_u$, $K_i = 1.2 K_u / T_u$, and $K_d = 0.075 K_u T_u$

The appropriate math:

$$K_i = \frac{K_p}{T_i} = \frac{0.6 K_u}{0.5 T_u} = 1.2 \frac{K_u}{T_u}$$
$$K_d = K_p T_d = (0.6 K_u) (0.125 T_u) = 0.075 K_u T_u$$

> Wikipedia: The Ziegler–Nichols tuning method is a heuristic method of tuning a PID controller. It was developed by John G. Ziegler and Nathaniel B. Nichols. It is performed by setting the I (integral) and D (derivative) gains to zero. The "P" (proportional) gain, $K_{p}$ is then increased (from zero) until it reaches the ultimate gain $K_{u}$, at which the output of the control loop has stable and consistent oscillations. $K_{u}$ and the oscillation period $T_{u}$ are then used to set the P, I, and D gains depending on the type of controller used and behaviour desired:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, it’s clear now and I really appreciate it very much!